# Select a data frame using string values and change its column name

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am trying to change the column name in a data frame. I would like to select the data frame using string values in combination with `eval(as.name(paste()))`.

Here is my code:

```
list <-c("a","b","c","d")

for (i in 1: length(list) )
{
assign(paste("tf_", list[i], "_0", sep=""), as.data.frame( ifelse ( !is.na( Data[[list[i]]] ),1,0 ) ) )

names(eval(as.name(paste("tf_", list[i], "_0", sep=""))))<-"blablabla"

}
```

When I am using the part `names(eval(as.name(paste("tf_", list[i], "_0", sep=""))))`, it returns me the expected name but when I want to assign a different name string value it shows me the error: ***target of assignment expands to non-language object***

Comment: Can you provide an example of your `Data` we can work with?

Comment: The `Data` is a different data frame with multiple columns from which some are named `"a","b","c","d"`. The assign part works fine. The problem is when I want to change the column name of the new data frame named `paste("tf_", list[i], "_0", sep="")`

Comment: If you want to change a `data.frame` column name you can do directly: `colnames(Data) <- list` if `Data` has same column number as `list` length.

Comment: try changing `2nd` line as:  `'df = get(paste("tf_", list[i], "_0", sep=""));
  df = "blablabla"`

Comment: @MKR 4 you mean `colnames(df)="blablabla"`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

Example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), x = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(b = rnorm(10), d = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10))
```

First use `mget()` to put your data frames in a list.

```
test <- mget(paste0("df", 1:3))
```

Current names:

```
> sapply(test, names)
     df1 df2 df3
[1,] "a" "a" "b"
[2,] "b" "c" "d"
[3,] "x" "y" "z"
```

Then create a vector of substitute names:

```
dud <- c(a = "n1", b = "n2", c = "n3", d = "n4")
```

Then loop over your list to change the relevant column names in all dataframes:

```
for(i in 1:length(test)){
  names(test[[i]])[names(test[[i]]) %in% names(dud)] <- dud[names(dud) %in% names(test[[i]])]
}
```

New names:

```
> sapply(test, names)
     df1  df2  df3 
[1,] "n1" "n1" "n2"
[2,] "n2" "n3" "n4"
[3,] "x"  "y"  "z"
```